# How can I select a specific GPU with TensorFlow and Yolov3? (tensorflow-gpu-2.3.1)

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I have two GPUS in my system (RTX 2070s). I am trying to apply Yolov3 using TensorFlow according to the following
[tutorial](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/Object-Detection-API).

However, it seems TensorFlow can't use a specific GPU. I had searched on the internet and found that you would need to change `'GPU'` to `/GPU:0` in  these lines of code:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

However, that doesn't work and keeps giving me the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices")
ValueError: Memory growth cannot differ between GPU devices
```

Any directions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Add this, each index range (0, 1) is the GPU:

```
tf.config.set_visible_devices(physical_devices[0:1], 'GPU')
```

Comment: https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/Object-Detection-API?fbclid=IwAR1dqk8mc7R4CPunEomtbqIhN67E2QoKZrcp9pSvsO6926iPOxPjwUjFsNM

Comment: Use `tf.compat.v1.config.experimental.set_visible_devices` for TF 1.15 or below, instead of `tf.config.set_visible_devices` which is for TF >= 2.0